# Error enabling Migrations in seperate projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class library project and a console app in a solution as two projects. I am trying to enable migrations. But I get an error 
Object Not set to an instance of object.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried multiple solutions including copying the app.config file in the Class Library as seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405873/how-do-i-configure-entity-framework-in-class-library-project)
and tried the solution I found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126711/enable-migrations-with-context-in-separate-assembly/18128768#18128768)

```
 enable-migrations -ContextProjectName RestaurauntData.RestaurauntRepository -StartUpProjectName RestaurauntReviews
```

Here is project Structure

[image]

Here is RestaurauntRepository:

```
   class RestaurauntRepository : DbContext
    {
        public RestaurauntRepository() : base("name = MyContextDB") { }
```

**App.Config**

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name = "MyContextDB"
      connectionString = "Data Source =(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog = RestaurauntDb;Integrated Security = true"
      providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You are trying to use Entity Framework 6.2.0 in a .NET Core project, which is not supported. Would it be possible for you to use Entity Framework Core instead?

Comment: Its not a core project